# RxJava - emit an observable every second

Tags: java, android, system.reactive, rx-java, kotlin

I am making a timer in Android using RxJava. I need to make a timer in RxJava to emit an observable every second. I have tried the following but with no luck. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
Observable.interval(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .timeInterval()
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe({Log.d(LOG_TAG, "&&&& on timer") })
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your code seems not to be called. Check whether it is executed and when. As of working with `Observable`, it is completely correct.

For example, I put your snippet inside `onCreate(...)` of my `MainActivity`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Observable.interval(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .timeInterval()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { Log.d("tag", "&&&& on timer") }
    // ...
}
```

And it works:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxkm5ol8l5idyji/observable_interval.png?dl=0]

Also, probably you don't need `.timeInterval()` because `Observable.interval(...)` itself emits sequential numbers within the specified rate, and `.timeInterval()` just transforms it to emit the time intervals elapsed between the emissions.

Comment: I do not need the .timeInterval() :) I removed it but still does not work :/

Comment: When I use this, I get a lint error: Missing Disposable handling

Comment: @KaranSharma , you can wrap it with disposable meaning you can write something like `disposable = Observable.interval()....` and then in onDestroy of Activity use `disposable.dispose()`

Answer (score 1):

In your `subscribe()` you don't consume the `longTimeInterval` object that's returned by the `timeInterval()` operator.

Correct version:

```
.subscribe(longTimeInterval -> {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "&&&& on timer"); 
}
```

Also I think you don't need the `timeInterval()` operator at all. `Observable.interval()` will emit an observable every second in your case, which I guess is what you want. `timeInterval()` transforms that to an observable that holds the exact time difference between two events occur, I doubt you'll need that.

Comment: Kotlin doesn't require the lamda parameter declaration in case of single parameter, so that's not the problem. `.subscribe { Log.d(...) }` is correct RxJava usage in Kotlin.

Comment: Good one, thanks for pointing it out! Got to look at Kotlin soon :)

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin & RxJava 2.0.2 simply define an Observable Interval with an `initialDelay` 0 and `period` 1 which will emit list item each second.

```
val list = IntRange(0, 9).toList()
val disposable = Observable
    .interval(0,1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .map { i -> list[i.toInt()] }
    .take(list.size.toLong())
    .subscribe {
       println("item: $it")
    }
Thread.sleep(11000)
```